# How can I add percentage lables to divergent bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

[image: Divergent charts]

I would like to add percentage labels to the bars.

```
df$Age1 <- df$Age..Yrs.
df %>%
mutate(Age1 = ifelse(Sex == "Female", Age1, -1*Age1)) %>%
#filter(Sex == "Female" | Sex =="Male")%>%
filter(!is.na(Age_cat))-> df

y_breaks <- pretty(df$Age1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Age_cat, y= Age1, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_breaks, labels = abs(y_breaks))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: structure(list(Age_cat = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("0-5years", 
"6-12 years", "13-24 years", "25-59 years", "60+ years"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
    "Female", "Male"), Age1 = c(49, 60, 46, 34, 39, 41, 14, 42, 
    -60, 37, 57, 28, 48, 36, -21, 43, -76, 36, 43, -70)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
+ geom_text(aes(label = str_c(Age1, "%")), vjust = 0, hjust = ifelse(df$Age1 < 0, 0, 1))
```